# Doctrine field has value in database but is null when mapped

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am having this strange issue with `Doctrine` .

When I use `find(id)` to find an entity, all fields are null except the id. I have double checked the values in database and they are are not null.

The strange thing is when I issue a native mysql query and try to find the entity that doctrine tries to fetch I get non Null value so probably it's a doctrine way of fetching values problem.

Here is my entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="hui_address")
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $client_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $region_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="`state`", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $state;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $zip_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", precision=10, scale=6, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $latitude;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", precision=10, scale=6, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $longitude;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="`status`", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $archive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Store", mappedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="address_id")
     */
    protected $Stores;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="Addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Client", mappedBy="PPBAddress")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="ppb_address_id")
     */
    protected $clientHQ;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Region", inversedBy="Addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $region;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!$this->created_at) {
            $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
        }

        $this->Clients = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->Stores = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (!$this->street || strlen($this->street) == 0 || !$this->city || !$this->city)
            ? "Address incomplete"
            : sprintf('%s, %s %s %s', $this->street, $this->city, $this->state, $this->zip_code);
    }

     public function __sleep()
    {
         return array('id', 'client_id', 'region_id', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'notes', 'status', 'archive', 'created_at');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the controller and view code ? And a example of the row that you access

Comment: thanks JGrinon for your comment , I found the problem I'll be posting the answer in a moment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with `doctrine`. It turns out that the `address` is fetched from a native query and only the `id` is selected , that's why I am getting the value for `id` and null for the rest.

This is how addresses are found :

```
$query = $this->getManager()->createNativeQuery('SELECT .... ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing getters and setters in the entity class.

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities *your bundle*
```

will generate them automatically

Comment: thanks for the answer , I omitted that for the sake of clarity , they are there in my code